# Can I perform Wudu whilst in the shower?

Tags: islamic-basis, wudu

I’ve heard some people mention that you cannot make wudu if your hair or feet are wet beforehand, but don’t know if this opinion is authentic

Answer (score 1):

There is no such restriction you can do wudu in the shower and you can do wudu  if your hair or feet are wet beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> Not all your head nor all your feet must be dry when wipe on them in
> Wudhu. Just part of the front part of the head, and one or more
> figures must be dry. The wiping must affect that front part of the
> head and one or more fingers. The affect is not transfer the wetness
> from the hand to the wiped areas.
>
> Wassalam.

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/ask/why-must-your-head-and-feet-be-completely-dry-when-you-wipe-them-in-wudu)